# On clicking table dynamic accordion table has to come

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-table, accordion

In this code I'm trying to display table inside table running PHP for loop. I'm able to get the data but unable fix the UI and accordion. I have created the table within the table but the second table is showing on side, I need that in the next row and also accordion should work.

```
 <div>  <h1>Payment Detail</h1> </div>

    <input type="text" id="search-payment-detail" />
    <a href="/admin/member-payment-detail">Add Member Payment Detail</a>
    {{--{{dd($payment_details)}}--}}
    <div id="prefetched">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>Mobile</td>
            <td>Role</td>
            <td>Status</td>
            </tr>
             </thead>
            <tbody>
         @foreach($payment_details as $payment_detail)
        <tr class="tableshow">
            <td>{{$payment_detail->sc_fullname}}</td>
            <td>{{$payment_detail->sc_email}}</td>
            <td>{{$payment_detail->sc_mobile_no}}</td>
            <td>{{$payment_detail->role}}</td>
            <td>{{$payment_detail->status}}</td>



            <td><table style="display:none;width:100%" class="collapseshow table table-bordered">
                @foreach($payment_detail->payementDetail as $pd)

                        <td class="width:100%">p1: {{$pd->p1}}</td>
                        <td>p2:{{$pd->p2}}</td>
                        <td>p3:{{$pd->p3}}</td>
                        <td>p4:{{$pd->p4}}</td>
                        <td>p5:{{$pd->p5}}</td>
                        <td>p6:{{$pd->p6}}</td>
                        <td>p7:{{$pd->p7}}</td>
                        <td>p8:{{$pd->p8}}</td>
                        <td>p9:{{$pd->p9}}</td>
                        <td>p10:{{$pd->p10}}</td>
                        <td>p11:{{$pd->p11}}</td>
                        <td>p12:{{$pd->p112}}</td>
                        <a style="display:none" href="/admin/edit-member-payment-detail/{{$pd->id}}">Edit</a>
                        <a style="display:none" href="/admin/delete-member-payment-detail/{{$pd->id}}">Delete</a>

                @endforeach
            </table>

     </td>

@endforeach
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

    </div>
    <div id="search-fetched"></div>

    <script>
        $('#search-payment-detail').keyup(function () {
            if ($.trim($('#search-payment-detail').val())) {
                $.get('/admin/search-member-payment-detail', {info: $('#search-payment-detail').val()}, function (data) {
                    var html = '<div>';

                   for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                       html += ` <table class="table table-bordered">
                       <tr>
                       <td>Name</td> 
                       <td>Email</td>
                        <td>Mobile</td> 
                        <td>Role</td>
                        <td>Status</td>
                        </tr> 
                           <tr>
                           <td>${data[i].sc_fullname}</td><td>${data[i].sc_email}</td><td>${data[i].sc_mobile_no}</td><td>${data[i].role}</td><td>${data[i].status}</td></tr></table>  <table class="table">`;
                       for (let j = 0; j < data[i].payement_detail.length; j++){
                           html+=`<tr>
                                    <td>p1 ${(data[i].payement_detail[j].p1 != null) ? data[i].payement_detail[j].p1 : ''}</td>
                                        <td>p2:${(data[i].payement_detail[j].p2 != null) ? data[i].payement_detail[j].p2 : ''}</td>
                                        <td>p3:${(data[i].payement_detail[j].p3 != null) ? data[i].payement_detail[j].p3 : ''}</td>
                                        <td>p4:${(data[i].payement_detail[j].p4 != null) ? data[i].payement_detail[j].p4 : ''}</td>
                                        <td>p5:${(data[i].payement_detail[j].p5 != null) ? data[i].payement_detail[j].p5 : ''}</td>
                                        <td>p6:${(data[i].payement_detail[j].p6 != null) ? data[i].payement_detail[j].p6 : ''}</td>
                                        <td>p7:${(data[i].payement_detail[j].p7 != null) ? data[i].payement_detail[j].p7 : ''}</td>
                                        <td>p8:${(data[i].payement_detail[j].p8 != null) ? data[i].payement_detail[j].p8 : ''}</td>
                                        <td>p9:${(data[i].payement_detail[j].p9 != null) ? data[i].payement_detail[j].p9 : ''}</td>
                                        <td>p10:${(data[i].payement_detail[j].p10 != null) ? data[i].payement_detail[j].p10 : ''}</td>
                                        <td>p11:${(data[i].payement_detail[j].p11 != null) ? data[i].payement_detail[j].p11 : ''}</td>
                                        <td>p12:${(data[i].payement_detail[j].p12 != null) ? data[i].payement_detail[j].p12 : ''}</td>
                                        <a href="/admin/edit-member-payment-detail/${data[i].payement_detail[j].id}">Edit</a>
                            </tr>`;
                       }
                   }
                    html += `</table></div>`
                    $('#search-fetched').empty().append(html);
                    $('#prefetched').hide();

                });
            } else {
                $('#prefetched').show();
                $("#search-fetched").empty();
            }
        })
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tableshow").click(function(){
        $(".collapseshow").toggle();
    });
});
    </script>
```

Comment: Your "table within a table" is lacking `<tr>`s. And your `<a style="display:none"` need to be inside a `<td>`.

Comment: Its not working Kerbholz...now im getting the data down as one <td> i want that data to occupy width 100% as a complete row without effecting the top table. Can You please help me..?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your html

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>Mobile</td>
            <td>Role</td>
            <td>Status</td>
            </tr>
             </thead>
            <tbody>
         @foreach($payment_details as $payment_detail)
        <tr class="tableshow">
            <td>{{$payment_detail->sc_fullname}}</td>
            <td>{{$payment_detail->sc_email}}</td>
            <td>{{$payment_detail->sc_mobile_no}}</td>
            <td>{{$payment_detail->role}}</td>
            <td>{{$payment_detail->status}}</td>

</tr> ** Close here first TR **
<tr>            ** Add Colspan **
            <td colspan="5"><table style="display:none;width:100%" class="collapseshow table table-bordered">
                @foreach($payment_detail->payementDetail as $pd)

                        <td class="width:100%">p1: {{$pd->p1}}</td>
                        <td>p2:{{$pd->p2}}</td>
                        <td>p3:{{$pd->p3}}</td>
                        <td>p4:{{$pd->p4}}</td>
                        <td>p5:{{$pd->p5}}</td>
                        <td>p6:{{$pd->p6}}</td>
                        <td>p7:{{$pd->p7}}</td>
                        <td>p8:{{$pd->p8}}</td>
                        <td>p9:{{$pd->p9}}</td>
                        <td>p10:{{$pd->p10}}</td>
                        <td>p11:{{$pd->p11}}</td>
                        <td>p12:{{$pd->p112}}</td>
                        <a style="display:none" href="/admin/edit-member-payment-detail/{{$pd->id}}">Edit</a>
                        <a style="display:none" href="/admin/delete-member-payment-detail/{{$pd->id}}">Delete</a>

                @endforeach
            </table>

     </td>

@endforeach
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ya6u2mtq/1/

Comment: Thanks alot...#Lalji #Tadhani, I need another help in this same table, I want that row expand as a accordion i.e., on click particular row should expand, can you please help me...

Comment: Thank You...#Lalji #Tadhani its working, Can you please help me in crearting accordions for onclicking particular row, that particular row should expand. Please help me in this..

Comment: use data table row expand it will help you in your case 
https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

Comment: Though I'm a beginner, I'm unable to get it. Can you please help me.